# How does this circuit with two PNP transistors work?

Tags: transistors, aviation-electronics

[image: How this circuit works for 0 and 5 volts of input of NPN transistor]

How does this circuit work for 0 and 5 volts of input of NPN transistor?

Why is Q18 needed in this circuit?

Comment: We are not your homework engine. Explain what you have found out so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: i need to know the use of the Q18(PNP)in the circuit.

Comment: What do you think it does? Tell us, what is the use of Q22 and Q26?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Above circuit is used for the switching purpose in the avionics related project. as per my analysis 1.if input voltage 5v ,Q22 BJT will turn on Due to that in the saturation region and it is passing 27V to the load.
2.if input voltage 0v ,Q22 BJT will turn off due to cutoff region.
Generally BJT act as a switch for 1 transistor is enough then what is use of 2 PNP transistor in the above ckt?

Comment: Turn on Q26. Where does its load current come from? What happens next? What doesthat cause to happen? Then ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q18 limits the current to the load. The limit is set by R309. Higher value = less current.
The circuit is quite similar to the one at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_limiter (id=605817308)

Comment from *Anonymous* contributor:

> "To be more precise the current limit is Vbe/R309 or 100mA +/- 15% "

Comment from *EM Fields*:

> "...when you connect 5V to the base, there's no current limiting resistor in either the base or the emitter to keep it from exploding".

So a base resistor to Q26 is critical and must be added. I had "unconsciously" added 100K in the LTSpice simulation results shown below.

**The picture below shows**

Green: 5V logic control

Blue: Voltage over your 1K resistor at the output port in your schematic.

Red: a system voltage from 0-27V.

With Q18 mounted:

[image]

Whithout Q18 the load will see the full system voltage.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your waveforms...may i know which tool you have used to generate waveform.

Comment: LTSpice (free).

Answer (score 3):

Q18 won't get much chance to do anything. When the input is 0V, the output is only leakage current into the load.

When the base of Q26 is connected to +5V the output will briefly rise to about 10V for some milliseconds before Q26 explodes and the output settles back down to 0V with only the smoking disembodied pins of the ex-transistor Q26 left on the PCB.

Answer (score 0):

In the original post, there seems to be a serious error with Q26's emitter going directly to ground, and then, when connected to to the load, as shown below, Q18 doesn't appear to be needed.

Run a simulation with and without it and you'll see that the signal into the 1000 ohm load stays a square wave about 4.5 volts high with a 5V square wave into the base of Q26.

Going into a little more detail, we have:

[image]

Note that in the OP's circuit, on the left, when V2 goes high and turns Q3 ON, Q2 will also be turned ON and Q1's base will be pulled to GND through R3 and Q2's C-E junction.

As current starts to flow through R3, it'll drop more and more voltage until it pushes Q3's emitter close enough to its base voltage to start turning Q3 OFF.

When that happens, the resistance of its C-E junction will start to increase, pushing Q2's base away from its collector, which will reduce its base current and start to turn it off.

With all that happening, when the current through R3 gets to around 4.5mA it'll drop 4.5V and, with Q1's base at 5V, that's more or less when everything will get stable.

Now, since the bulk of R3's current flows through R2, the voltage drop across R2 will be: E=IR = 4.5mA * 68R = 306 millivolts.  That's Q1's base-to-emitter voltage, and since it won't be enough to cause any major reduction of Q1's collector-to-emitter resistance, Q1 might as well not be in there.

To prove it we remove it, along with R2, and when we do the circuit reduces to the voltage regulator right,  where the voltage across the load varies as a function of Q6's base voltage, regardless of the values of R6 or V3.

Well... there are supply voltage and load current limits but, to a first approximation, that's what the circuit does.

Comment: :we ll get around 25.2v across the 1kohm resistor when Q22 turned on.27v-(R309)* collector current.

Comment: Why isn't your NPN emitter example connected directly to ground?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1: I guess I unconsciously realized the OP's drawing had a serious error in it and fixed it.

Comment: I feel really dumb about this, but why is it a mistake to connect Q26 emitter to GND?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1: Because when you connect 5V to the base, there's no current limiting resistor in either the base or the emitter to keep it from exploding. :-)

Comment: Then we are two who designs being unconscious. ;) I unconsciously added a base resistor to Q26. Will add a note about in my answer. Thanks!